# Can someone indentify this font, please?

Tags: fonts, text, typography

So, I've been looking this font everywhere on the internet as I can, like WhatTheFont, Font Finder, Google Lens, but I can't find anything, not even close to it.
Can someone please indentify it?
It's for design graphic project on my school.[image]

Comment: The image seems quite distorted. Where is it from? A shirt print? Can you find other examples which are flat? Could be designed specifically for this shirt. If you only need to write a single word you could perhaps draw the letters yourself.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shirt print out. I'll edit the image

Comment: I did change the image, maybe it's better?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like its this one:

[Arsenal 19-20](https://footballfonts.com/arsenal-2019-2020-cup-font-ttf-otf/) but a bit edited/shorter